# The archive doesn't exist error when running ant jar task

Tags: ant, build, jar

I'm running an ant build file that creates a Jar. The task looks like this:

```
<target name="generator-app" depends="clean,compile">
    <jar jarfile="${gen.App}">
       <manifest>
       ...
       </manifest>
       <fileset dir="${classes}">
          <include name="com/mypackage/**" />
       </fileset>
       <zipfileset dir="${jars}" />
     </jar>
</target>
```

The build file runs and creates the file as expected when I run it on Linux, but fails with this error on any other platform:

```
BUILD FAILED /home/user/build.xml:287: the archive doesn't exist
```

I tried using destfile instead of jarfile, but the same result occurs. The archive does not exist indeed, but the purpose of the task is to create it.

Is there any limitation on certain platforms or any way to correct this?

Comment: Could it be the ${jars} directory that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I tried using a newer version of ant, and now the error indicates exactly what is missing (a jar to be packaged in the jar to be created).

Answer (score 2):

Forward slashes don't seem very windowy to me :) Maybe you should convert your slashes based on your os? Do you pass this path somewhere?

Comment: I always run on Unix-based systems so this is not a problem :)

Comment: @FailedDev: Ant uses slashes, even on Windows.

Comment: @JBNizet I had some problems with forward slashes on windows before.